# logic behind the MKCoordinateSpan

Tags: ios, mkmapview

working on MKMapView, I want to be have clear concept on MKCoordinateSpan.
My interest is, when we give the value for the MKCoordinateSpan, what is the reference parts, 
or what is the range of each latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MKCoordinateSpan defines a span, i.e. a delta, in the latitude and longitude directions to show on a map. Along with a point you can then define a region to display on a map.

For example:

```
|<---- deltaLat  ---->|
|---------------------|---
|                     | |
|                     | |
|                     | |
|                     | |
|          +          |deltaLon
|      (lat,lon)      | |
|                     | |
|                     | |
|                     | |
|---------------------|---
```

Here you can imagine a centre point (lat,lon) about which you have a deltaLat and a deltaLon.

So (lat,lon) would be a CLLocationCoordinate2D and deltaLat, deltaLon would form a MKCoordinateSpan.

Comment: region.span.latitudeDelta=x; what is the minimum and maximum value for x.

Comment: minimum value of x is 0.0 and maximum value is 180.0

Comment: when I use value greater and equal than 120, it gives this error "bad readSession [0x80cdd60]" what this means.

Comment: This is the clearest explanation regarding deltas!!! Thank you!